# Make HTTP requests to GCP Python VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-requests, virtual-machine, httprequest

I am new to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and wanted to find out how to call my script from a request on my app I am building.

I want to be able to parse a variable into my python script running on my VM, and then return the result.

Or even call a function in one of my python files, and return the result.

If someone could give an example of a basic request parsing in a function and capturing the output, or link me to an example, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could try the [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) python module to create a server to handle HTTP requests.

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of "call my script". You can use a localhost REST API (Flask is a good framework) or even call the PHP interpreter as a program from your code (more challenging). You could even embed PHP into your program. More research on your side is required.

Comment: Hi Trey, hope you are well, so that I understand the scope of the question better, are you looking how to create an app with python OR how to do it with GCP? If you are looking for how to create a web app - flask is a good solid framework that is perfect for things like what you are looking for. If you are looking for how to host this app on a GCP - it isn't any different from a hardware server. Things to keep in mind are - you probably want to set a static external ip, so it doesn't change on reboots and configure a firewall rule to allow the inbound traffic. Let me know know, happy to help.

Comment: Of are you looking to know how to CALL something that is running on GCP, ie the scope is your local environment and not the remote GCP part.

Comment: Hi, I am creating an app in React Native, it is a translation app, so giving an English sentence to the method, it will use the model (python) to translate and return a French sentence.

Comment: Hey Trey, I am still not sure about what the question is, to be honest. What is it you are looking to do on a GCP side?

Comment: Try something, show us where you are stuck and then it will be easier to guide you. Your question is too broad here.

Comment: @jabbson Hi, essentially on GCP, I have trained a Tensorflow model using Python, and currently to test the model works, I call a function ```import translate from model... print(translate("..."))``` but I want to take user input from my mobile app, and call that function using the user input. I have read up on some things called Cloud Functions, but not enough yet to see if these will fulfill my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Trey, does [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/how-to-serve-deep-learning-models-using-tensorflow-2-0-with-cloud-functions) looks like something you are after?